# Firebase Cloud Functions - access debug or release database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a project for both Android and iOS that's using cloud functions for same app behavior and consistent data storing. For now we were debugging apps on single database, storage and authentication.

The problem is when I switch to `release variant` I want functions to operate on `release` database, storage and auth.

I've been searching for an answer to my problem and all I've found was this: [How to access multiple Realtime Database instances in Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47861381/5273427)
but it doesn't help too much.

Is there a way to go about that without making another Firebase project for release variant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so basically just a while after posting this question I've found [official firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/) that helped me resolve this issue.

**Short answer**: no, you have to create another project in Firebase as described in guide.