# Firebase real-time database auth rules work in simulator but not on app

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following rules setup

```json
{
   "rules":{
      "comments":{
         "$postOwner":{
            ".write":"auth.uid == $postOwner",
            ".read":"auth.uid == $postOwner",
            "$postID":{
               "$postCommenter":{
                  ".write":"auth.uid == $postCommenter"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

While testing the rules in the simulator they work as expected when i as a `postCommenter` write to that destination.

When i attempt to write using my app in the following way:

```
activeDB.ref().child('comments').child(*postOwnerID*)
        .child(*postID*).child(*myAuth.uid*).set('comment here')
```

The above gives me a permission denied error.

However if i change that final `.write` condition to `true` it does work so I know its not a matter of a wrong path. I have manually made sure that my `firebase.auth().getUserId()` was the same as the destination I was attempting to write was in which case it matched.

So unless I'm not seeing something simple it appears rules containing `auth.uid` aren't being enforced properly in this case. Not sure what else could be causing this behavior.

Other than to note this is not my main database I'm attempting to write to, its a secondary one in case that could be one of this issues

Update: Here is the error log -

```
logger.ts:115 [2021-07-25T23:24:32.688Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: set at /pending/8ni1vZMwexft5xDkjBItdziS1133/-MeSH813lCjnVI6Apw7b/Dpiv7zsM7ZabcF5qqBysRjVsAnM22 failed: permission_denied 
Z @ logger.ts:115
ie.warn @ logger.ts:206
xe @ util.ts:161
(anonymous) @ Repo.ts:526
(anonymous) @ PersistentConnection.ts:641
tn.onDataMessage_ @ PersistentConnection.ts:673
wt.onDataMessage_ @ Connection.ts:321
wt.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ @ Connection.ts:313
(anonymous) @ Connection.ts:210
yt.appendFrame_ @ WebSocketConnection.ts:302
yt.handleIncomingFrame @ WebSocketConnection.ts:354
mySock.onmessage @ WebSocketConnection.ts:224
```

And more importantly I copied these rules into my main default database and it worked as expected. So certainly looks like a problem with auth on newly created databases

Comment: are there more details on the permission denied error ? a log ?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez I updated the post with the log and new info. I can't find anything in the docs suggesting I need to do something different with security rules for additionally created real-time databases

Comment: Check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied

Comment: No that question isn't applicable. But this one is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460464/firebase-realtime-database-sharding-rules

Comment: did it help you solve the problem ?

Comment: yes. I'm not sure how to properly link it as solved or to reference that one officially

Comment: @tallanwhite, just close this one, since is a duplicate