# FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Database initialized multiple times

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have multiple database instances in my firebase app. I am trying to write into three database instances in firebase cloud functions. My understanding by following this [document](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/11/easier-scaling-with-multi-database.html) is no need to initialize multiple apps for each database instance. We can initialize one and pass in the database url. As a side note, I have another function with similar kind of functionality where I have trigger event in one database and write data to other database instance and it works fine.

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
const app = admin.app();

export const onStart = 
functions.database.instance('my-db-1')
        .ref('path')
        .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    return await onCreate('my-db-1',snapshot,context);
        });
 export const onStartDb01 = functions.database.instance('my-db-2')
        .ref('path')
        .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
            return await onCreate('my-db-2', snapshot, context);
        });

async function onCreate(dbInstance: string, snapshot: 
functions.database.DataSnapshot, context: functions.EventContext): 
Promise<any> {
    const defaultDb = app.database(defaultDbUrl);
    const actvDb = app.database(actvDbUrl);

    await defaultDb.ref('path')
        .once("value")
        .then(snap => {
        const val = snap.val();
         ---do something and write back---
       });
    await actvDb.ref('path')
        .once("value")
        .then(snap => {
        const val = snap.val();
        ---do something and write back---
    });
    return true;    
 }
```

But when a db event is fired, it logs the error as below

> Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Database initialized multiple times. Please make sure the format of the database URL matches with each database() call.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the **entire** code that doesn't work the way you expect.  Especially how you initialize each variable.  The question should have enough information so that anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: It still doesn't look complete to me.  What exactly are `defaultDbInstance` and `secondDb`? They have no assignments here.

Comment: @DougStevenson They are the database names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to initialize a separate `app()` for each database instance.

Based on Doug's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877115/209103) that should be something like this:

```
const app1 = admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const app2 = admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
```

And then:

```
const defaultDb = app1.database(defaultDbUrl);
const actvDb = app2.database(actvDbUrl);
```